# Unable to access a post's insights

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-insights

When I wanted to get insight data of one post using the source     https://graph.facebook.com/[POST ID]/insights, I got this response:

```
{
   "data": [.
         ], 
   "paging": {.
       "previous": "https://graph.facebook.com/[POST ID]/insights?format=json&since=-86400&until=0", 
       "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/[POST ID]/insights?format=json&since=0&until=86400"
   }
}
```

The posts are created by fan page days before, but I still can not get insight data. However, when I using another fan page, I can get entire data for every post.
  Why? Is there anybody can give me the reason? Dose Facebook record insight according to the fan page type? If so, which type of fan page can own insights data for its posts?
Will be very appreciate if someone can help.

Answer (score 1):

Have resolved. 
Facebook seems to provide insights to Pages with a proper number of users who liked this page.
I don't know the exact number, someone says it's 30, but I just asked 22 friends to like my page, then I got the insights for the posts on the page.
Hope this answer can help guys still confused.